# mongodb error: ConfigurationError: Port number must be an integer

Tags: python, json, mongodb

i am new in mongodb. i am creating free database using mongolab. my database name is enron and this database i have create on collection name is mbox. my system have one json file.i am trying to import this json file into collection using python.my database connection connect sucessfully but importing json file then error occure.please give me proper solution.

```
 import os
 import sys
 import envoy
 from bson import json_util # Comes with pymongo
 from pymongo import MongoClient


 client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://user:user123@ds033499.mongolab.com:33499/enron')
 r = pymongo.MongoClient('mongoimport --host mongolab.com --port 033499 --username    pramod_jadhav --password p9822581103 --collection mbox --db enron --file C:\Users\sachin\Documents\IPython \ch06-mailboxes\data\enron.mbox.json')
 print 'json import sucessfully'
```

Comment: This is your client **library** pymongo. You **can't** run a command line program with it. Your first statment is a connection for your code to use, and the argument is a connection string. You don't call `mongoimport` in this way. Just run it from the command line.

Comment: how to connect shell for free remote database

Comment: Question is low quality and shows no research

Comment: Google was your friend: http://docs.mongolab.com/migrating/#import-and-export

Answer (score 2):

Here, we need to parse url so that it can handle special char(like @) correctly. For that import urllib and use method `urllib.parse.quote([mongo _lab_url])`,

In your case,

```
import urllib

db_url = urllib.parse.quote('mongodb://user:user123@ds033499.mongolab.com:33499/enron')

client = MongoClient(db_url)
```

should work !!!